# empty C:\fakepath\.. file upload in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove the selection from the input type=file, when something is entered in the textarea. The following Jquery fails, because IE replaces the local drive and directory path to something like, C:\fakepath\file.txt.
Many thanks in advance.

```
$("textarea#txt_id").live('keyup', function(){
    $('input[type=file]').val('');
});

<textarea name="txt" id="txt_id" rows="8" cols="64"></textarea>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file_id" />
```

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535128(VS.85,loband).aspx. The `value` property (which jQuery is setting) is read only.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the file control with the same html will clear it

```
$('#fileId').html($('#fileId').html());
```

Or using just java script...

```
function clearFileInputField(fieldName) {
    document.getElementById(fieldName).innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById(fieldName).innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: See the closing `/>` of an `<input />` tag? They don't have inner html.

Answer (score 1):

Have a solution for you. First check if browser is IE, next use encodeURI to encode all the file path and name, you have to do that first in order to correctly capture the unescaped chars like "\".  Then just replace, its working for me:

```
var browserName=navigator.appName; 
if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
    var soloNombre = encodeURI(soloNombre);
    soloNombre = soloNombre.replace("C:%5Cfakepath%5C","");
    var soloNombre = decodeURI(soloNombre);
    alert(soloNombre);
}
```

Works like a charm.